# Is this substance drywall joint compound?

Tags: drywall, asbestos, drywall-mud

I need to get a sample of some drywall joint compound for asbestos testing in a house I'm renovating. I pulled away some of the base boards in the corner and found something that I believe to be joint compound, but I need someone to verify before I take a sample and send it in.

[image]

[image]

I'm looking at the tan colored substance by the nail in the corner (I highlighted it in the picture). Is this drywall joint compound?

FYI, we have already had some lab tests done and found asbestos (chrysotile) in the popcorn ceiling in one room and the linoleum flooring in the kitchen (currently covered up by laminate). The abatement company recommended checking the joint compound in the wall.

### Update

This substance was indeed drywall joint compound and it did contain asbestos, which is a bummer. Now on to abatement...

Comment: Are you trying really hard to not damage the drywall above the baseboard line? If that's not a concern, put a putty knife between the paper and the mud in that L shaped divot on the right. Push toward the corner and you should get mud, texture and paper tape.

Comment: No it's fine to damage this area since this wall is going away. So the stuff with the L shaped divot is joint compound?

Comment: Asbestos wouldn't be added to joint compound, mastic, or adhesives. Those things aren't fuel sources, so there's no need to fireproof them.

Comment: The stuff around the L shaped divot is probably a combination of texture and joint compound. If you dig to the corner, you'll probably get both. (In a perfect world, the paper corner would be in there as well, as that would indicate that the stuff under it and the first layer over it is joint compound.)

Comment: What makes you think there's asbestos in the joint compound, or anywhere in your house, for that matter? When was it built?

Comment: @FreeMan We had lab tests done and they came back positive for chrysotile in both the popcorn ceiling in one room and the linoleum under the kitchen floor. The abatement company recommended that we also test the joint compound so here we are. The house was build in 1969.

Comment: @dandavis The abatement company said that there can definitely be asbestos present in the joint compound and it needs to be tested.

Comment: That would have been good info to have included in the question initially. If you look at the [tag:asbestos] tagged questions, you'll see that there's lots of (likely) needless paranoia. Providing the context that you've got a very credible reason to be concerned will avoid lots of wondering from those looking at your question.

Comment: @FreeMan Trying not to be a jerk here but I provided you with that info as soon as you asked for it. I can't control what assumptions you're making about my situation. I didn't ask "do you think I should test this substance for asbestos?", I asked if that substance was joint compound.

Comment: I saw that you quickly updated your question, and that's good. Unfortunately, we get a _lot_ of questions that are missing a lot of details. Some get updated promptly (as you did - THANK YOU!!), others never do. As noted, there is a lot of hype and fear around asbestos (and other things) as I noted, and much of the concern in unwarranted. Your situation _is_ different and that was very obvious to you, but not to us.

Comment: That's fair, I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what I see is the paper for the drywall. There are adhesives but I see wrinkled paper if there is a filler in that point not the paper a clear photo of the tan material would be needed to make a guess. Over the years I have seen everything from sheetrock mud to modeling clay used to patch drywall with even mortar in a few cases.
Note sheetrock or drywall mud can discolor yo a brown or iron oxide color when metal corners are used and if there is moisture in the room other than the torn paper to the left of the nail I don’t see tan.

Comment: Sorry, I realize that I wasn't being clear about what I was referring to in the pic. I put a border around the material I'm thinking is the joint compound.

Comment: That’s just mud that was put on thick.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I'm confused, isn't "mud" the same thing as drywall joint compound?

Comment: There are many different types topping, hot, and standard most pros refer to them all all as mud.

Answer (score 1):

Yes in the loosest sense of the term.   Yes it was something that was used just like joint compound.   So it is either joint compound or a relative.

You can tell that it was gradually increased towards the corner, probably to get things closer to a 90 degree angle and just feathered out from the corner.